# RegEx to short the date

Tags: javascript, regex, date

I have a date format like **2015-12-14 10:15** and i have to search a string (large data) based on date that contains multiple dates (like in log file).

But the problem is the string file may contain dates like **2015-12-14 10:17**, **2015-12-14 10:19** (last digit not multiple of 5). I have to get the data from the file after the date **2015-12-14 10:15** (last digit not multiple of 5).
If I am searching through regex of **2015-12-14 10:15** i.e **/2015-12-14 10:15/** that fails in this case because the exact date is not present in the string file.
I need to get string as on date or after the passed date (i.e. 2015-12-14 10:15).

String like::

> [2015-12-14 10:04:11,232] I recommend you to read my first article that I have written for beginners. [2015-12-14 10:18:22,367] in this article too, I’ll show you how you can add the “date” filter to an HTML template using an expression. BEGIN[2015-12-14 10:18:22,368] Date to format either as Date object, milliseconds (string or number) or various ISO 8601

And when I use regex to short the date that fails because date is not present in that string. So what regex should I use so that I can get the string on passed date or after the time in passed date.

Desired Output:

> [2015-12-14 10:18:22,367] in this article too, I’ll show you how you can add the “date” filter to an HTML template using an expression. BEGIN[2015-12-14 10:18:22,368] Date to format either as Date object, milliseconds (string or number) or various ISO 8601

Guide me to write the regex for this.

Comment: `Java` or `Javascript`?

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252868/regex-reference-and-its-fate

Comment: I don't think you should use only regex for that, one possible solution for your problem is get the date and convert to datetime and than compare if it is after or before the time you need. You could get the date with the pattern: \[(\d+-\d+-\d+\s\d+:\d+:\d+),\d+\]

Comment: @ConradoCosta I think pick all the date from log file and convert them to Date obj is not the right way. exact Regex required..

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a regex that will find a date greater than an arbitrary passed in date. You could potentially write a long regex that finds datetimes that occur after a specific ISO 8601 date.  You could even write a script that could generate such a regex for a given input.

I think what you want to do is just find a regex that will match any ISO 8601 date.  Take that regex, modify that regex to include the square brackets around the date, and to include the text after the date match up until the next match/EOF.

You'll then use javascript to loop through all the matches and check for dates that are greater than the input date.  If all the dates are ISO 8601, you shouldn't need to convert them to date objects, a string compare would be sufficient.